# Is $A x x^{\top} A$ equal to $A x^{\top} A x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $p \times p$ real value symmetric matrix and $x$ is a $p$ dimensional vector. I am wonder whether
$$A x x^{\top} A = (x^{\top} A x) A?$$
If not? in what case, they are equal?

PS: They have the same trace.

Comment: Context? What have you tried yourself

Comment: Apart from lacking context, your notation is ambiguous... Maybe insert some parentheses, and tell what shape of matrix $x$ is? Can you clarify?

Comment: If the right side is supposed to be $(x^\top Ax)\cdot A$, then the answer is no.

Comment: Have you tried calculating an example, Xiangjie?

Comment: @BenGrossmann - $x^\top A x$ is a scalar value, so the dot product does not apply here.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou It's a 1 by 1 matrix and I think that's Ben's point: you can't multiply a 1 by 1 matrix by a p by p matrix. Really, one should write like $(x^\top Ax) \otimes A$ or $\langle Ax, x \rangle A$ or something. This should be a hint in itself that the quantity is unusual and is not equal to the more natural quantity $Axx^\top A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but

$$ Ax\,x^{\top}A=Ax\,\left(Ax\right)^{\top} $$

since $\left(Ax\right)^{\top} = x^\top A^\top $ and $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you. I See they only share the same trace.